# apple-touch-icon web app home screen icon for BlackBerry PlayBook?

Tags: html, icons, blackberry-playbook, apple-touch-icon

Is there an equivilant to `<link rel="apple-touch-icon">` for the BlackBerry PlayBook?

I would like to show a custom icon when users add my web application to their home screen. The application is purely web-based (not WebWorks), so there is no code on the device.